# How does enum in Swift work?

Tags: swift, enums

I am very new with Swift, and Objective-C for that matter. I am reading Apple's book on Swift programming and confused about enum. In the book, there is an example

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "ace"
        case .Jack:
            return "jack"
        case .Queen:
            return "queen"
        case .King:
            return "king"
        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
let ace = Rank.Ace
let aceRawValue = ace.rawValue
ace.simpleDescription()
```

which display "ace", I got that. But I do not understand why the following code does not work the same way:

```
var r:Rank
r.Ace.simpleDescription()
```

I know there is something I do not get, but I read this section of the book several times and still do not get it.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got that. But I do not understand why the following code does not
>   work the same way:
>
> ```
> var r:Rank 
> r.Ace.simpleDescription()
> ```

There is couple things.

First, your first line is just a *declaration*. You did not *initialize* the variable. Before you use it, you need to initialize it.

Second, the `case Ace, Two, Three, Four`... gives you a list of possible values variable of type Rank might have. When you assign to it, you can assign only value from this list. Your `r` does not have any "Ace", or any "Two" by default. And even after you initialize it, e.g. `r = .Ace`, `r.Ace` is not the proper way to access value of `r`.

So you need to do it this way:

I got that. But I do not understand why the following code does not work the same way:

```
var r:Rank = .Ace
r.simpleDescription()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var r = Rank.self           //add self here
r.Ace.simpleDescription()   //"ace"
```

Or you can use it this way too:

```
var r:Rank

r = .Ace

r.simpleDescription()   //"ace"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Adding self makes sense to me. I wish I could check your answer, too!